# Understanding non-blocking IO in Node

Tags: node.js, express, nonblocking

What is the difference between these codes?

***First*

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.post('/', function (req, res) {

    console.log('Procesando abastecimiento...');

    var rawData = '';

    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        rawData += chunk;
    });

    req.on('end', function(){
        console.log('Data recibida: ' + rawData);
        res.end();
    });    
});
```

**Second**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.post('/', function (req, res) {

    console.log('Procesando abastecimiento...');

    var rawData = '';

    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        rawData += chunk;
    });

    req.on('end', function(){
        console.log('Data recibida: ' + rawData);    
    }); 

    res.end();   
});
```

If I close the connection (`res.end()`) inside 'end' event's callback, will the client wait until all data is read? I don't understand the difference, I just know that my code is faster using the second way. Can you explain me why?

Comment: if you call res.end outside it is called immediately as soon as a post request comes. You should use the first code not the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example you set the `res.end();` instruction to be executed on the request `end` callback (i.e. then the `end` event is raised).

In the second one you call `res.end();` right away without awaiting the request to end.

You can think of it as if the instruction `req.on('end', ...)` is a function that sets up a handler for an event that will come in the future, but the code there is not executed until the event is received.